# Image (.png) not shown in Chrome, firefox and mobile-safari

Tags: html, image, firefox, google-chrome, mobile-safari

I have this image:

```
<a href="home.php" id="logo"><img src="images/myimages.png" alt=""></a>
```

It works  only using Safari. It's not shown in Chrome, firefox or Safari 'Mobile' (iPad, iPhone).

Any reason?

Comment: Could you post the URL to that (or an example) page?

Comment: Looks completely valid. Should work on all those browsers. Most likely you have an error some other place, and the browser went into quirks mode.

Comment: this is just an example.... the image is on the top left corner... as I said it shown in safari only...http://www.app-dream.com/test/test.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your file seems to be a PSD (Adobe Photoshop) file that has been renamed to .png.

Store it as a proper PNG.

Comment: @Shaul it seems Safari can deal with PSDs.